# How to load svg images in compose properly?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to load SVG file in Jetpack compose, but it turned out to be black when i run it on the phone.

[image]

Here is the image from my phone.

[image]

I don't want to use `tint` modifier, because it is going to load the SVG in a single color.

Answer (score 17):

Use `Image` composable instead of `Icon`. Icon is doing tint by default. [Source](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/tools/dokka-devsite-plugin/+/master:testData/compose/source/androidx/compose/material/Icon.kt?q=Icon) - you can read the docs for `Icon`.

> Icon component that draws [imageVector] using [tint], defaulting to [LocalContentColor].

Also - you can just use `painterResource` instead of `ImageVector.vectorResource`.

And just for the future - never attach code as a screenshot on StackOverflow. Just attach code

Answer (score 2):

You can use **painterResource** with tint option to tint a vector.
It will not cover whole svg in one color.

```
Icon(
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_crop_square),
    contentDescription = "Localized description",
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(AssistChipDefaults.IconSize),
    tint = color,
)
```

Result:

[image]