# How to display .svg Image URL in JetPack Compose?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I have svg image Url, I want to display the image in Jetpack Compose.

Comment: You can check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835321/how-to-load-svg-images-in-compose-properly

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Coil SVG extension](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/svgs/).

Add the dependencies in your `build.gradle`

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.0.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.0.0")
```

Then, add it to your call..

```
@Composable
fun SvgImageSample() {
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .decoderFactory(SvgDecoder.Factory())
            .data("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Android_robot.svg")
            .size(Size.ORIGINAL) // Set the target size to load the image at.
            .build()
    )
    Image(
        painter = painter,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```